# Printer not using full page width

Tags: printing, epson

I have an Epson LX-300 Printer Driver, but I can not get it to print on the full width of a regular US Letter page. Whatever I configure, the printer just prints about 60% of the page width. As if the page were very small, leaving large empty spaces. I have tried printing from Firefox, Chrome, and OpenOffice. I have tried setting the "Paper Size" to different settings. I have taken out all margins. I have used "Adjust to fit on page" and printed on "100%" (and 150% and 50%⁾. I have installed the printer under Ubuntu 10.10 using this tutorial: http://all-about-ubuntu.blogspot.com/2008/12/epson-lx-300-printer-driver.html, and I have tried using this driver: http://www.openprinting.org/printer/Epson/Epson-Dot_Matrix. I have also tried by just using Ubuntu default setting.

All of this has given no results. I can not get this printer to print on the full width of the page.

Anybody any idea?

Comment: A couple of questions (1) What happens when you try print a test page from within the Printer Properties dialog?  (2)  Are you setting the printer settings in the application or from the system menu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have the wrong driver. Install a different one by going to: `Administration > Hardware > Printing`. Try all drivers from Epson, one of those should do the job.

Comment: This in fact worked... changing it to Epson 9-pin series!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to print a test page as asked by [jwernerny](https://askubuntu.com/questions/33793/printer-not-using-full-page-width/46549#comment37790_33793) in comments section?

What is the printer model?  I have Lx 300+ and I not facing this problem.
I could print a test page also in a decent way.

I used the same driver PPD file `Epson-Dot_Matrix-epson.ppd.zip` for the printer Epson Lx 300+ and I am able to print in the whole page.

I did some setting changes in firefox where I fire prints.
On the address bar, typed `about:config`

Type `header` on the filter bar, then right-click each of those prefs and select Modify, then backspace or use Delete to wipe the characters - then click OK.

Type `footer` on the filter tab, then right-click each of those prefs and select Modify, then backspace or use Delete to wipe the characters - then click OK.

Search for `margin` then:
print.print_extra_margin Change from 90 to 0
print.print_margin_bottom delete and make 0
print.print_margin_left delete the current value and make it  0.04
print.print_margin_right delete the current value  and make it 0.1
print.print_margin_top delete and make 0

Repeat the all of the above changes for settings specific for the printer ( eg: print.printer_Epson-Dot-Matrix.print_margin_top)

Left and right margins I chose based on my needs. Header/Footer I wanted to wipe off, so I removed it.

But then my print  was what I expected to get.

Please let me know if this works or come back with more questions so that we can resolve it.